# Find the missing number inside circle

Tags: mathematics

Amongst three given circles with different values find the value of missing number.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izgs2.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Is this puzzle any relation to this one? https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96656/circle-puzzle-critical-startegy

Comment: @JMP considering the OP just reposted this with a 4 and not a 14, it would appear so

Comment: Yes but i want to know the logic correct behind this from u brilliant guys.

Answer (score 3):

It could be

> 14

With the following rule:

> Multiply the right and left numbers by 2. Add the left, bottom and right and subtract the top:
>
> Left circle: 5*2 + 1*2 + 3 - 2 = 10 + 2 + 3 - 2 = 15 - 2 = 13
> Right circle: 5*2 + 1*2 + 14 - 9 = 10 + 2 + 14 - 9 = 26 - 9 = 17
> Middle circle: 5*2 + 1*2 + 6 - 4 = 10 + 2 + 6 - 4 = 18 - 4 = **14**

Comment: Haha, great minds!

Comment: @hexomino oh wow, almost the exact same time :P

Answer (score 2):

Given that each circle has five numbers and there are only two given examples there will be many, many things that will work but the simplest example I can think of is the following

> centre = 2*left + 2*right + bottom - top

This means that the missing number is

> 2*1 + 2*5 + 6 - 4 = 14